# jQuery scrollLeft

Tags: jquery

I was looking at the tutorial at http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/. I tried creating something similar myself for understanding, it turned out to be more complex than I thought. How do I use scrollLeft?

I created a simple fiddle to test it http://jsfiddle.net/sryKu/2/

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test Link 2</a></li>
...
```

CSS

```
#carousel .wrapper {
    position: relative;

ul {
    position: absolute;
```

JS

```
$wrapper.scrollLeft(itemsPerPage * itemWidth);
```

But its not scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method for that:

```
$wrapper.animate({scrollLeft: itemsPerPage * itemWidth});
```